# Is there a way to run a system command without escaping the command

Tags: r, escaping

what is the recommended way of running a shell command through `system` or `system2`.
I find myself always having to escape things for it to work.

Is there a way that avoid having to escape all special characters ?

example:

```
bash$ # the following works fine
bash$ grep -i "something" some_file | grep -Po '(\d|-)+ (\d|:)+\.\d+'
      # what I'd like
R> cmd <- magic(grep -i "something" some_file | grep -Po '(\d|-)+ (\d|:)+\.\d+')
R> system(cmd, inter = TRUE)
```

Comment: Speaking as someone who knows shell but not R: What does R have by way of quoting formats? Can you assign your exact command to a native-R string without escaping it?

Comment: By the way -- be very, **very** careful about where substring elements come from. If `some_file` (or `something`, for that matter) is actually a name coming from a variable, then you have a shell injection attack unless you're using [`shQuote()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/shQuote.html) to escape it.

Comment: Hello, my question is R oriented, nothing prevents me from escaping all the \ in R and it will work fine, I am looking for a "clean" way

Comment: Yes -- the "clean" way is to use a language that lets you do something akin to what some other languages call a "quoted heredoc", permitting a string within which all contents are literal up to an arbitrary end-sigil. Of course, that's contingent on the language supporting that feature.

Comment: (perhaps this should be *only* tagged `r`, and not tagged shell at all? If the only open questions are about R language's quoting rules and literal formats, there's no real shell-specific question here at all).